# ggplot changing legend title and labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to change legend title and key labels to display custom information. This is what I have.

[image]

This is the code I have tried.

```
g + scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition",          
      breaks=c("IL,1","IN,1","MI,1","OH,1","WI,1","IL","IN","MI","OH","WI"),
      labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))
```

Thank you

Comment: Pleas show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: bp + scale_fill_discrete(name="Experimental\nCondition",
                         breaks=c("ctrl", "trt1", "trt2"),
                         labels=c("Control", "Treatment 1", "Treatment 2"))

Answer (score 0):

Seems `OP` is looking for a way to use both `colour` and `fill` for data points and then customize the `legend` of his own choice.

In the example provided as part of OP, last '5' points has used same color as `white`. It should be keep in mind while defining custom `fill` color.

Another point is that only points with `shape` value more than `20` allows use of both `color` and `fill`. That's why `shape` has been taken as `22' in below example.

The sample data:
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(A = 1:20, B = sample(30:40,20,TRUE), C = sample(1:10,20,TRUE))

```
ggplot(df, aes(A, B, colour = factor(C), fill = factor(C))) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6, shape = 22, size = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="Experimental\nCondition", 
    values = c("gray","pink","coral","seagreen","ivory","white","white","white","white","white"),
    labels=c("IL,1","IN,1","MI,1","OH,1","WI,1","IL","IN","MI","OH","WI"),
    breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10")) +
  scale_colour_manual(name="Experimental\nCondition", 
    values = c("red","green","yellow","blue","pink","ivory","gray","coral","seagreen","orange"),
    labels=c("IL,1","IN,1","MI,1","OH,1","WI,1","IL","IN","MI","OH","WI"),
                    breaks=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"))
```

[image]